# Rails 4 - rendering a collection with a partial name different to the variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following partial `posts/post_preview` in my project:

```
.post
  %h2= link_to(post.title, post)
  .post-body= simple_format(post.body)
  %ul
    - post.tags.each do |tag|
      %li= tag
```

I want to render this partial for a collection name `@posts`, like so:

```
render partial: 'post_preview', collection: @posts
```

However, `render` by default passes each member of the collection as a local variable named after the partial. Is there any way I can change this so each member of `@posts` is passed into the partial in a variable named `post`?

Comment: Good thought. why you need this kind of feature ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html
Check this for changing the name
Let say you have products and want to use as item then just do like

```
<%= render partial: "product", collection: @products, as: :item %>
```

i recommend you to check this too.
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/PartialRenderer.html